# Search Script for Google sheet and display on web

Tags: ajax, web, search

I am kind of a newbie here.
I am working on a set of database which is now ready in google sheet from.

I'd the user to either search for, Name, Last name or Student ID on the web and then, display list of search result. And finally click on one name on the list to display only that name database.

Is there any available code for this?

I tried to search but they're not exactly what I am looking for

Thank you,

Nond

I tried to look for a code, try to use it but it is not exactly what I am looking for.

I am expecting a sample code that I might be able to continue working on this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.